# Regex for numbers without dots

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression that accepts only integer numbers like this:

```
12 valid output 12
(12) valid output 12
[12] valid output 12
12foo valid output 12
12. not valid
.12 not valid
12.12 not valid
```

I have something like this:

```
^(?![.])\d+(?![.])
```

Comment: what do you mean accept only numbers.. Do you have a sample code to show here?

Comment: Can you show us the full extent of brackets and parentheses?

Comment: Also, would a period in a sentence be valid, e.g. `I am here.` ?

Comment: Every number without dots is valid. Mine input is one word from txt file e,g, [[12]] and it detects 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your post example and comments the right pattern should be this:

```
(?<![.\d])\d+(?![.\d])
```

This is very close to your one.
Differences:

- you didn't set the check to sure that are no digits on both sides too. You checked only `.` symbol
- you used negative look-ahead on left side of `\d+`. You need to use negative look-**behind** (not ahead) if you want to "look" left "negatively".

**Note**: I don't use starting symbol `^`, but I hope it's not big deal for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^\.]+$
```

Comment: Edited first post. I need to detect 12 from input e.g. foo(12) but do not detect 12.12 from foo(12.12) so your answer is not correct.

Comment: you use the supplied regex to check if valid match (does not contain dot) and then use another regex to capture the number on only valid matches.

Comment: It was requested to allow numbers only, this also matches letters.